# how do I customize format items in ckeditor config

Tags: editor, ckeditor

in my CKeditor config I have this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Format' ] },
    ]
};
```

I want this config only show heading2 & heading3 but it shows all headings.
how can I do that?

tanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is described in documentation - see [`config.format_tags`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-format_tags).

E.g.:

```
config.format_tags = 'p;h2;h3;pre';
```